# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Sound Recording

Tags: sound

My Audio recording and Audacity do not work reporting: "Cannot start reading from the stream/pipeline." What can I do? Oskar Petersen

Comment: Install `pavucontrol` and look around through the tabs, specifically the input, and see if something is muted or set to a dummy device or different hardware. That's where I'd start.